# Retrieve Perl Hash Values using Javascript functions

Tags: javascript, jquery, perl, hash

I want to change the values of a select box based on the value in other in a Web Page.

When the page is loaded I store the keys and values in a hash. So when I change the value in field1 it calls javascript function and the values in field2 should change as per the hash.

Hash:

```
%hash = ('factory1','model1','factory2','model2','factory3','model3');
```

jQuery Function:

```
\$('#factory').change(function(){
                var factoryVal = \$(this).val();               
               \$('#model').val()="$hash{"+factoryVal+"}" ;
 });
```

How can I do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
use JSON;
my %hash = ('factory1','model1','factory2','model2','factory3','model3');
my $json_str = encode_json \%hash;

print qq{

  var hash = $json_str;

}, q{

  $('#factory').change(function(){
      var factoryVal = $(this).val();
      $('#model').val( hash[factoryVal] );
  });

};
```